# Binary tree filling (NullPointerException)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, binary-tree

I need to fill a binary tree using only class `Node` with recursion. However when I try to use left and right children I get a `NullPointerException`. How should I fix it?

```
public class Node {

    private Integer key;
    public Node right;
    public Node left;

    public void addValue(Integer value) {
        if (key == null) {
            key = value;
            right = null;
            left = null;
        } else {
            if (key > value) {
                left.addValue(value);
                left.right = null;
                left.left = null;
            } else {
                right.addValue(value);
                right.right = null;
                right.left = null;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node node = new Node();
    node.addValue(5);
    node.addValue(4);
    node.addValue(3);
    node.addValue(2);
    node.addValue(1);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please add the calls to addValue you are doing and the stacktrace to help us determine where the issue is? Apparently you never create new Nodes (you never call the constructor) so both right and left will always be null.

Comment: where do you initialize `left` and `right` ?

Comment: I have added it.

Comment: i think that I initialize them with help of this     public Node right;
    public Node left;